# What if the virtual destructor defined in derived class, but not the top of hierarchy? C++

Tags: c++, virtual, destructor, hierarchy

I wonder is it correct to define a base class with no virtual destructor, and define inherited classes with the virtual one? What would actually happen if I do that?

Comment: It depends how you use the classes.

Answer (score 5):

If you `delete p` where `p` is of type `X*` but actually points to a `Y` which is derived from `X`, you have undefined behavior unless `X` has a `virtual` destructor. If `Y`'s destructor is `virtual` but `X`s destructor is not it changes exactly nothing.

Answer (score 2):

**If** you intend to do

```
delete pB;
```

where `pB` is of type `Base*` and `pB` might point to an object of type `Derived`, where `Derived` is a (direct or indirect) derived class of `Base`, **then**,

you must declare a virtual destructor for `Base`.

So long as you don't intend to do this, it is fine for `Base` to not have a virtual destructor.

In particular, if you have class `B1` with a non-virtual destructor, and a class `B2` that derives from `B1` with a virtual destructor, and a class `D` that derives from `B2`, it is fine to use a pointer to `B2` to delete an object of type `D`, since `B2` has a virtual destructor... but it would be undefined behaviour to use a pointer to `B1` to delete an object of type `B2` or `D`, since `B1` does not have a virtual destructor.

In any case, the idea of a function being `virtual` in a derived class and non-`virtual` in a base class is **confusing**, so I would not do it unless I had a very good reason.

Comment: I have a template class Singleton, which is parametrized with the actual class that should follow the singleton pattern, so I wonder should I use virtual destructor for it or not.

Comment: @user2443626 Could you be more specific?

Comment: Thank you, Brian, you explained me exactly what I wanted to know!

Answer (score 0):

It won't work if you don't declared virtual in parent class.

```
[~/cpp/VirtualDestructor]$ cat main.cpp
class A
{
public:
    ~A() {}
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B() : val(new char) {}
    virtual ~B() { delete val; }
private:
    char* val;
};

int main()
{
    A* x = new B;
    delete x;
}
[~/cpp/VirtualDestructor]$ valgrind ./run 
==20382== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==20382== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==20382== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==20382== Command: ./run
==20382== 
==20382== 
==20382== HEAP SUMMARY:
==20382==     in use at exit: 1 bytes in 1 blocks
==20382==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 1 frees, 17 bytes allocated
==20382== 
==20382== LEAK SUMMARY:
==20382==    definitely lost: 1 bytes in 1 blocks
==20382==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20382==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20382==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20382==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20382== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==20382== 
==20382== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==20382== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
[~/cpp/VirtualDestructor]$
```

`B` instance is pointed by a `A*` pointer. Then when you `delete` it. It will go through the destructor of `A` if `A`'s destructor is not `virtual`

Answer (score 0):

A virtual destructor allows you to invoke the correct destructor with just a pointer to the baseclass. Without the virtual destructor, `delete base_ptr` will only invoke the base-class' destructor (or invoke undefined behaviour). However, whether the destructor call is dispatched dynamically depends only on the base class, so if the baseclass doesn't make it virtual, this will not suddenly become a virtual dispatch if some derived class adds a virtual destructor!

Notes:

- If the baseclass doesn't have a virtual destructor, don't use it as a baseclass. At most, use private/protected inheritance, but not public inheritance.
- If you write the baseclass but don't want to require a virtual destructor (common when writing mixins), you can make the destructor protected instead.

These two advises prevent accidental calls to the non-virtual baseclass destructor.